# Inappropriate value for attribute "security_groups": element 0: string required

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm not sure why I'm getting this value.

I have this resource in **bastion/main.tf**

```
resource "aws_security_group" "bastion_sg" {
  name   = "${var.name}-bastion-security-group"
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id

  ingress {
    protocol    = "tcp"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    protocol    = -1
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.name}-bastion-sg"
  }
}
```

here is my output for that **bastion/outputs.tf**

```
output "bastion_sg_id" {
  value = aws_security_group.bastion_sg
}
```

My eks module in my root directory **main.tf**

```
module "eks" {
  source = "./eks"
  name   = var.name
  key_name = module.bastion.key_name
  bastion_sg = module.bastion.bastion_sg_id
  vpc_id = module.networking.vpc_id
  private_subnets = module.networking.vpc_private_subnets
}
```

my variables in my **eks/variables.tf**

```
variable "bastion_sg" {
  description = "bastion sg to add to ingress rule of node sg"
}
```

lastly, my **eks/main.tf** where the error is occuring

```
esource "aws_security_group" "node-sg" {
  name   = "${var.name}-node-security-group"
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id

  ingress {
    protocol        = "tcp"
    from_port       = 22
    to_port         = 22
    security_groups = [var.bastion_sg]
  }

  egress {
    protocol    = -1
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

I tried it with and without the `[]` for the security_groups argument and when I did it without I got the `set of strings required` error and when I added the `[]` I got this error

```
on eks\main.tf line 95, in resource "aws_security_group" "node-sg":
│   95:     security_groups = [var.bastion_sg]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.bastion_sg is object with 13 attributes
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "security_groups": element 0: string required.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
output "bastion_sg_id" {
  value = aws_security_group.bastion_sg.id
}
```

Comment: One way to ease debugging of situations like this is to always annotate input variables with type constraints. If this `var.bastion_sg` were declared as `type = string` then Terraform would've raised the error inside the `module "eks"` block instead, making it clearer that it was the caller of the module that was providing an incorrect value, rather than a problem within the module itself. (That is, unless you consider a input variable without a type constraint to be a problem. )